# Find document by key only, in Firestore

Tags: firebase, database-design, firebase-realtime-database, data-modeling, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently converting my Firebase real-time live database to use the new version, Firestore.

I would like to find a document by key. Previously, in Firebase real-time I could do something like this:

```
getSingleRouteById (key) {
   const ref = firebaseDb.ref('/data/')
   // now search for data with that key several nested layers down
   return ref.child(key)
      .once('value')
      .then((snapshot) => {
         return snapshot.val()
     })
}
```

After reading the new docs I can't find a way to achieve this in Firestore. Please, note I only know the key, so I need to search all documents, without knowing the actual path/reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a native way to do this. Part of the issue is there is no uniqueness to key across multiple paths, so when looking for the key 'key' in `/data/` you could have `/data/123/key` and `/data/231/key`, meaning there are multiple possible answers.

The only way to achieve this would be to create your own inverted index. Whenever you `create` a document, use say Cloud Functions to automatically add a document to `/keys/` with the id of key and update a field called `paths` to include the full path the key. `paths` should be map.

You can support deletions to by listening for that event and updating the inverted index.

For the above example, you would then have a document in `/keys/` with the following:

```
Id: key
paths: {'/data/123/key' = true,
        '/data/231/key' = true}
```

Comment: Ah ok that explains why I couldn't find the key. Thanks for your easy-to-understand answer. I will go down the route of adding a separate 'keys' collection with a path object.